# Retrieve SMS sent after a specific time

Tags: android, sms, android-sqlite

I have a background service that listens to changes to Android SMS content provider. I store the last recorded id of the message that my Service recorded and using it, I want to find the number of messages that were sent when the service was Stopped/Killed.

So when the service is started again and another message is sent, I want to use the timestamp of the last recorded message. I use the below code to do this. My problem is that the cursor always returns 1 record irrespective of how many messages are sent when the service was killed before its restarted.

```
String COLUMN_NAME_DATE = "date"
String[] projection = new String[]{COLUMN_NAME_ID, COLUMN_NAME_DATE};

Cursor newMessagesCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.parse(SMSManager.SMS_URI_SENT),
                projection,
                COLUMN_NAME_DATE + "> ? ",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(lastMessageTimeStamp)}, null);

int newMessagesCount = (null != newMessagesCursor) ? newMessagesCursor.getCount() : 0;
```

Any pointers would be helpful. Let me know if there is any alternative approach as well.

**Edit:** Adding code to retrieve the lastMessageTimeStamp.

```
Cursor messageCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
        Uri.parse(SMSManager.SMS_URI_SENT),
        projection,
        COLUMN_NAME_ID + "= ? ",
        new String[]{ lastMessageId}, null);

if(null != messageCursor && messageCursor.moveToFirst()) {      
   Long lastMessageTimeStamp = Long.parseLong(messageCursor.getString(messageCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_DATE)));
}
```

Complete Source code for this class is located at:
https://github.com/midhunhk/message-counter/blob/unicorn/messageCounter/src/main/java/com/ae/apps/messagecounter/observers/SMSObserver.java

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right timestamp? That is, how and when are you getting `lastMessageTimeStamp`? Have you checked that value when the above code runs? Which is the one message you do get from that query? Is it always the most recent one sent?

Comment: I query the SMS table with the `lastMessageId` and read the timestamp. Will update the code with that as well. I think the one message is the recent one, will confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using a different approach.

It seems like when we query the table `SMSManager.SMS_URI_SENT` as in the question, it is only returning 1 row which is the last message that was sent.

```
Cursor newMessagesCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        Uri.parse(SMSManager.SMS_URI_ALL),
        MessagesTableConstants.SMS_TABLE_PROJECTION,
                "person is null and " + MessagesTableConstants.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + "> ? ",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(lastMessageTimeStamp)}, null);
```

I query for `SMSManager.SMS_URI_ALL` and check for `person` column as null which represents messages that are sent.